# Direct Query Blank Values Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, directquery

I have imported data via Direct Query however one particular field displays some blank records (which is expected). These blank records are supposed to be used as a filter. However, the slicer does not recognize or pick up these Blank values. I have tried multiple IF statements, SWITCH statements, ISBLANK statements, power query editor, all in an effort to try a simply change these blank values to a value of 1 so that they appear and I can filter accordingly. Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this?

NOTE: I cannot provide data as it is sensitive.